# how to simulate a Laplace function of a PID controller in the time domain with LTspice

Tags: ltspice, pid-controller, laplace-transform

I tried to simulate a Laplace function of a PID controller with LTspice in the time domain, but an error message appears "The laplacian is singular at DC".
[image]

cs1 is the controller, so I just have a unit jump (Ugen) + controller (cs1)

with KP=0.9995594504821;  KI=0.0000772197554;  KD=0.00540381443834925;  Tp=KD/100

Comment: Without seeing the subcircuit one can only guess, but I'd guess that the integral part uses a bare `1/s`, which indeed can cause problems. If so, the solution is to add a pole way up, somethig like `1/(s+1p)`. However, this means that `Laplace` expressions are used, and they are known to be problematic in `.TRAN`.

Comment: thanks, but if I use the formula with 1 / (s + 1p), my results are no longer correct.
Can you also build a PID controller like this? with 1 / (s + 1p) in the I-part instead of (1 / s)

Comment: *p* should be a very small value. Lower than the lowest frequency (in rad/s) you are interested in simulating correctly.

Comment: @ast30277 There must be a misunderstanding, `1p` refers to `1 pico`, as in `1e-12`, which means you'll have a pole in the hundreds of GHz region. I can't see how that could affect your results in a meaningful way. And, yes, for Laplace expressions this trick is common.

Comment: thank you very much, it was very helpful.
My results were not affected